# Flutter not appearing in languages & framework setting on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, installation, settings

After installing Flutter and Dart plugins on Android Studio, I wasn't able to locate flutter in my settings. Please help [flutter_not_found_in_setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qveiq.png)

Comment: check flutter doctor output.

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.18.0-7.0.pre.44, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287,
    locale en-AU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

Comment: Everything is fine on flutter doctor output but not the android studio setting as I am unable to trace flutter or dart in my languages & frameworks section.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I also got the same problem.

Comment: Anybody with a solution for this? Flutter doctor returns no errors but I can't see flutter in my settings either. NVM I think I figured it out.

Comment: Any solutions, anybody??

Comment: I think it's not showing by default (or in my case). But as soon as you open a Flutter project then it's showing flutter and dart option.

Comment: Any solution, guys?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I re-installed (I had installed but I don't know why it was showing not installed ) flutter plug-in and the problem was solved.

Settings -> plugins -> Markateplace -> Flutter

Comment: Same thing happened to me and I don't think this is the fix.

Comment: In my case, `Settings` also has not a `Plugins` item to select.

Answer (score 6):

Please try opening an actual flutter project then checking the Settings -> Languages & Frameworks again. The menu changes if you have an actual flutter app open. I just used the default sample values.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to Go to:

`File >> Invalidate cache / Restart >> select Invalidate cache / Restart`.

That's it, flutter option will reappear.